# Build Successfully but not running junit files using Apache Ant

Tags: java, hibernate, junit, build, ant

I am new in Apache ant to build the project. In my Project i used MySQL,junit and hibernate library. I am working on bitbucket pipelines so some suggest use to ant. So i am creating the build.xml file and in there the proecess is clean,build,run junit test case. I did many research how to learn these things but i am stuck in some place. I am success in clean the directory and build also but i am stuck to check junit failure test case. I tried to run these test case in eclipse it shows that test case fail but if i run through ant it always say build successfully. I will provide my project structure .

```
+HiberTest
  --HTest
     --lib         
        --mysql
        --junit
        -- Hibernate..... so many library 
     --src
        -com
           -test
             **so many junit files**
        -com
           -utils
             **so many files**
     --classpath
     --.settings
     --.project
     **and many more files**
  --build.xml
```

Here is my build.xml files

```
<project basedir="." default="junit" name="Hibernate test">
    <property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars" />
    <property name="src.dir" location="HTest/src" />
    <property name="build.dir" location="HTest/bin" />
    <property name="target" value="1.8" />
    <property name="source" value="1.8" />
    <property name="test.dir" value="HTest/bin/com/test" />

    <path id="classpath">
        <pathelement location="bin" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/junit3.8.1.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/byte-buddy-1.10.7.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/classmate-1.5.1.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/dom4j-2.1.1.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/FastInfoset-1.2.15.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.0.Final.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/hibernate-core-5.4.11.Final.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.7.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/jandex-2.1.1.Final.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/javassist-3.24.0-GA.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/stax-ex-1.8.jar" />
        <pathelement location="HTest/lib/txw2-2.3.1.jar" />
    </path>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="init" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="${build.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                <exclude name="**/*.launch" />
                <exclude name="**/*.java" />
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target depends="init" name="build-project">
        <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}" />
        <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="${build.dir}" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
            <src path="${src.dir}" />
            <classpath refid="classpath" />
        </javac>
    </target>


    <target name="junit" depends="build-project">
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath" />
                <pathelement location="HTest/src/com/utils" />
            </classpath>
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
            <batchtest>
                <fileset dir="${test.dir}" includes="*.java" />
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>



</project>
```

```
It always gives me this output:- 

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory F:\Repository\Agile\HiberTest\HTest\bin

init:
    [mkdir] Created dir: F:\Repository\Agile\HiberTest\HTest\bin
     [copy] Copying 1 file to F:\Repository\Agile\HiberTest\HTest\bin

build-project:
     [echo] Hibernate test: F:\Repository\Agile\HiberTest\build.xml
    [javac] Compiling 3 source files to F:\Repository\Agile\HiberTest\HTest\bin

junit:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

**I want to check that if junit test fail then stop the build process and if passes all without error and then i want to create executable jar files**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: I deleted my answer as it no longer makes sense since you edited the question.

Comment: Hello i changed but nothing works. Can you check again the code please. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question any more.  You removed the build target, but it still shows up in the output?  Is it just that you've got haltonfailure="no" when it should be yes?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change the output build to junit i changed. I changed the **haltonfailure** to **yes** I need to these if my any test case fail then i need to stop the build.. Thanks @martin

Comment: Problem solved then?

Comment: No Sir it gives the same thing even i added this line also to run multiple test cases but nothing work ```<formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
   <batchtest>
    <fileset dir="${test.dir}" includes="*.java" />
   </batchtest>```

Comment: So the junit task is now running, not logging anything? Try running "ant -v" see if you get more info from the task.

Comment: Hello there are so many output comes but in junit it says like ```[junit] Starting test thread 0
    [junit] Ending test thread 0```

Comment: Sounds like your tests might be passing ok?

Comment: yes i runned my test cases in eclipse and its working fine or can i send you the my whole project if you want

Comment: Not really :)   I guess I don't see what the issue is - if the tests pass the build should not stop - is that right?  What are you expecting to happen that isn't?  (I have to go offline soon ...)

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience . I am changing my test cases into fail or success but the output gives same when running the build.So If my test case fail the build should be stop but it doesn't happen.. It always says that successfull build. I need to stop the build.

Comment: Did you find anything @martin

Comment: Hi Vivek - I can't really help with the detail.  One thing I notice though is the log from ant -v seems to show the junit tests are running (starting, ending), contrary to the title of the question.  I suggest you try to reduce the build complexity to isolate the issue.  So if you create a simple test that fails in eclipse, and run just that one test in the junit task, it should be easier to diagnose that one test.  You can also run ant -debug for more verbosity, but that's best done on a minimised build that isolates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The build starts in "build" and the hierarchical never call junit. Try to change:

```
<target depends="build-project" name="junit" />
```

Comment: Hello @Wender i have change the file but it doesnt effect. If you want to see that i change the file please see above the code. Thanks

Comment: any solution for this @Wender

Comment: I guess the problem is the ${test.dir} ( value="HTest/bin/com/test"). There are no Java files in this folder, only classes. You may change the from "bin" to src "dir".